# how to add special character when the next line key is pressed?

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to add a special character when the nextline button(key) is pressed in android mobile.

Plz help me to handle the Android 2.2  keyboard.

Am trying to use this code but its not supported me...

```
etDetail.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
              int charCode = event.getUnicodeCharCode();
              if (charCode == 0) {
                // it's probably Firefox
                int keyCode = event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode();
                // beware! keyCode=40 means "down arrow", while charCode=40 means '('
                // always check the keyCode against a list of "known to be buggy" codes!
                if (keyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                  doOnEnterKeyPressed();
                }
              } else if (charCode == 13) {
                doOnEnterKeyPressed();
              }  
            }
        });
```

What packages are added to do this task or give some ideas

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error/bug?

Comment: The method addKeyPressHandler(new KeyDownHandler(){}) is undefined for the type EditText

Comment: KeyDownHandler cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Is there a specific third party lib available to resolve this

Comment: plz any one send a solution for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this. I hope this code snippet will help you

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                doOnEnterKeyPressed();

            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```